# Adding Shell Scripts to CVS from windows

Tags: linux, version-control, shell, cvs, tortoisecvs

I am going to add some Linux shell scripts to CVS. Can I download the scripts using SSH secure shell client to windows and then add to CVS using Tortoise CVS client? (Just for ease... We have nice GUI in tortoise otherthan using cvs commands :)) Will it destroy the privileges set from the Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will destroy the privileges you've set.  You might be able to preserve permission using SSH and Cygwin, but then adding the files via Windows and TortoiseCVS will destroy the permissions again.

Your best bet is to use command line CVS on the server, it isn't hard... just make sure that CVSROOT is set to the path for CVS:

export CVSROOT=:local:/home/username/cvs

then add the shell script files to CVS:

cvs import -m "Imported sources" myshellscripts

See the following for more details:

http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/cvs/cvs_6.html